# Eclipse and ADK - Attempt to run Emulator: "Internal Error...."

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adk

When I attempt to run the emulator, I get an error message:

> `"An internal error occurred during: "Launching DroidPro".
>   Path for project must have only one segment."`

Any ideas what this means?

Answer (score 0):

Check this post: http://www.pedrorainho.eu/blog/aninternalerroroccurredduringlaunchingapp

I had this problem. After a little search i've managed to find that the problem was related with avd. All I needed to do was select a valid avd in project properties

Comment: He has a valid emulator. The Project Name seems to be missing from the Launch Properties and that is what the error message is saying. It's related to not being able to determine the Name of the Project. This has been answered here several other times

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  I did run a few searches--I guess I didn't use the right search terms because I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Project Name entered in the Launch Properties dialog box?? Does not sound like it is..

Answer (score 0):

If the problem comes while running the application, first launch the emulator and then run your app. But first of all make sure you have created an AVD.